# Set 'cshtml' data and return a string

Tags: c#, razor

I have a confirmation email template `.cshtml` as following:

```
<html> 
    <head>
        <title>company name: Email Verification - Action Required</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head> 
    <body> 
            Thanks for signing up for company name!
            <br/>
            <br/>

            Thank you for signing up to company name. Please press the link below to confirm your email address <br/>
            If you did not sign up for company name, please ignore this email, and accept our apologies for the inconvenience.

            <br/>
            <br/>

            <a href="@Model.ConfirmLink">@Model.ConfirmLink</a>

            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>

            Thanks,<br/>
            The <a href="http://company name.com" >company name</a> Team                       
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is there a mechanism I can set data (`@Model.ConfirmLink`) and get back a result as `string`? (not manually replace string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [RazorEngine](https://razorengine.codeplex.com/), which uses the same syntax as Razor does, but gives you the ability to render the text without the need of ASP.NET MVC.

How your code would work:

```
string template = yourHtmlCodeAsString;
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { ConfirmLink = "http://.../" });
```

You can load that template string from a file, a resource, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use Razor as template engine for emails.

I use this class.

```
public static class EmailFactory
{
    public static string ParseTemplate<T>(T model, string templatesPath, EmailType emailType)
    {
        string templatePath = Path.Combine(templatesPath, string.Format("{0}.cshtml", emailType));
        string content = templatePath.ReadTemplateContent();

        return Razor.Parse(content, model);
    }
}
```

- `templatesPath` - is the path where my cshtml views for email are.
- `EmailType` is and enum that has elements that are the same as the view namse from the templatesPath directory.

The essence is `Razor.Parse(content, model);` it takes a string that is a valid razor view and a model and merges them together. Same as the views in ASP MVC.

Comment: What is the equivalent of this in the new razor engine? This is obsolete now