# How to pass var to function in C#

Tags: c#, razor, razorengine

How I can pass var to function?

I need to create the following unknown data model, and pass it to my function, which shout parse it using RazorRenderer:

```
var emailData = new {name="value" , name2="value2" ... , nameN="valueN"}
```

The function can't receive var, so we used object, but then we can't convert it back, and we get an exception when call:

```
string htmlBody = render.Parse(File.ReadAllText(TemplatePath), emailData );
```

When I do the following, in same function it works:

```
var emailData = new { UserRequest = "hello", UserEmail = "name@domain.com" };
string htmlBody = render.Parse(File.ReadAllText(TemplatePath), emailData);
```

But when try to pass the emailData to the function it not work, any idea?

I can do the rendering out of the function and pass the result to the function, but I thought it may be nice to do it internally inside the function.

BTW- I tried JSON Serialize and Decerialize, with no luck.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33019305/993547.

Comment: Is there any reason why you need it to be an anonymous object? Typically when passing an object outside of the function scope, it's best to create a concrete type.

Comment: What exception do you get when calling `render.Parse` in your first sample?

Comment: @KeithRousseau,  because I have more than one template, and I prefer to manage it internally, and today we do it in different way by passing var to FluentEmail.Email, so I only wanted to replace one line on the existing code, instead of.....  I could create a specific object for each template, but then it is much work for me and lots of changes in existing code.

Comment: @PatrickHofman the exception: "Unable to compile template. 'object' does not contain a definition for 'UserEmail' and no extension method 'UserEmail' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: What is your template like?

Comment: @PatrickHofman : the template can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33463224/set-cshtml-data-and-return-a-string/33463343#33463343

Comment: Lol. That one looks familiar...

Comment: Anyway, I think I need to decide whither to create a specific class for each template, then in RazorRender.parse<The Class TYPE> , or simply pass the rendered string to the function and that's it.

Comment: What happens if you start your template with `@model dynamic`.

Comment: well @PatrickHofman, I'm trying not to make too much changes to existing stuff, as well not to corrupt/break anything,  so I'll ask to do the render and send me the string, this will be the minimal solution :)

Comment: "render" - what is type of this object?

Comment: @jos it seems to work at my end. Can you share some more context what is going wrong?

Comment: @PatrickHofman it can't work, if you pass the var var emailData , to a function, which this function  call render.Parse, it will failed, because you can't do something like: render.Parse<object>(File.ReadAllText(TemplatePath), emailData);, where the emailData is an object instance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it is not possible. Anonymous type names cannot be represented in user code hence there is no way to make them an input parameter to a function.

Your best bet is to create a type and use that as the return from the query and then pass it into the function. For example,

```
class YourDataClass {
  public string ColumnName; 
}

var query = (from name in some.Table
            select new YourDataClass { ColumnName = name });
YourMethod(query);
```

...

```
YourMethod(IEnumerable<YourData> enumerable);
```

In this case though, you are only selecting a single field, so it may be easier to just select the field directly. This will cause the query to be typed as an IEnumerable of the field type.

Comment: "Anonymous type names cannot be represented in user code hence there is no way to make them an input parameter to a function." > That is just wrong. They can be represented, what ever that means, and they can be passed around.

Comment: @PatrickHofman While I can understand that the wording in this answer is wrong, the sentiment is correct. There is no way to refer to an anonymous type explicitly. The only way they can be passed around is 1) as plain object, as the OP is doing already, or 2) in generic methods where the generic argument is inferred. (Sorry for the double notification, it was too late to edit my earlier comment.)